# Modules - Include <compare> header cannot find 'std::partial_ordering

Tags: c++

I have this error popping up: "*error C3774: cannot find 'std::partial_ordering': Please include  header*". I will try to explain in stages:

**1)** Project compiles (no error at all).

**2)** Recent file module is added (recentfile.ixx and recentfile.cpp) to the project (should be part of core module). If recentfile.ixx is as below:

```
module;
//inclusion of <filesystem> and <list> headers    
export module recentfiles;
```

then project compiles and no error is issued.

**3)** All remaining same and if I change the last line:

```
export module core:recentfiles;
```

again no error.

**4)** Now it is included to core.ixx:

```
export module core;
export import :recentfiles;
//some other export import
```

"*error C3774: cannot find 'std::partial_ordering': Please include < compare > header*".

At this stage including the < compare > header to recentfile.ixx does not help.

**5)** To solve the problem:

```
module;
#include <compare>
export module core;
export import :recentfiles;
//some other export import
```

now the project compiles again.

Why do I have to include the < compare > header or what am I missing?

Compiler: MSVC, Version 17.5.2

Comment: Is it MSVC? It still has bugs in the module support.

Comment: Yes forgot to add, it is MSVC Version 17.5.2

Comment: Report it as a bug. Microsoft has a place for it. Yesterday was testing modules and got something similar but different. Could be related.

Comment: It seems like a bug to me too. I will just wait to see what others might say and then report it.

Comment: Related community question, closed as not a bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Template-exports-requiring-importing-of-/1425979

Comment: @tunc, questions does not seem related.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly hypothesize (and agree with others) that the error below is an MSVC compiler bug.

> "error C3774: cannot find 'std::partial_ordering': Please include
>  header"

I see this error if module_x uses `import module_y` and module_y includes `<filesystem>`

Comment: I ran into so many weird errors with modules that I reverted back to header/cpp format and life is back to normal. Especially if you are producing DLL and some files are modules and some are not, tons of errors are produced... Needless to say modules are great but still experimental...

Comment: @macroland, Thanks much for comment and I'll be sure to avoid mix-and-match of non-module cpp files and modules, in the same dll.